# Nominalstil immer vermeiden?

Tags: style

Sollte man den Nominalstil à la

> "Angesichts der gestiegenen Schichtarbeitsbelastung ist eine Verzögerung bei der Inbetriebnahme der Maschine unter Zuhilfenahme der Computermethoden  zu Stande gekommen"

oder

> Hiermit bitten wir um Entschuldigung für das Verzögern bei der Verbuchung Ihrer Überweisung

vermeiden, wie es viele Ratgeber schon seit den 1980ern empfehlen, oder hat er doch einen Platz im modernen Sprachgebrauch?
Was ist sein **passender** Verwendungsbereich? Briefverkehr, Erläuterungsberichte, Beschwerden, Einsprüche vielleicht?

Comment: Was ist denn die Begründung für die Kritik am Nominalstil?

Comment: @userunknown: hab ich mich auch gefragt & vermisse es in der Frage, u.a. hier https://www.kapiert.de/deutsch/klasse-9-10/sprache-untersuchen/stil/verbalstil-und-nominalstil/ wird gesagt, der Verbalstil sei lebendiger & einfacher zu verstehen, Wikipedia listet auf, der Nominalstil habe weniger Nebensätze und sei in wiss. Beiträgen verbreitet. Aber sonst nicht, warum davon abgeraten wird.

Answer (score 5):

Ich persönlich nutze Nominalstil hauptsächlich in zwei Fällen. Der erste wäre in Betreffzeilen. Nominalstil hilft die nötigen Information möglichst kurz zu fassen. Eine weitere Anwendung wäre in Logs zu Tätigkeiten: "14:30 Anpassen der Stellschrauben" etc...
Außerdem nutze ich es gelegentlich, wenn ich Sätze unpersönlich halten möchte:

> "Entschuldigen Sie das Verzögern der Verbuchung Ihrer Überweisung" vs. "Entschuldigen Sie, dass wir erst jetzt gebucht haben".

Das kommt gelegentlich vor, wenn ich nicht sicher bin, wen ich anspreche (im Schriftverkehr) oder wenn ich einen Vorgang oder Zustand nicht auf eine Person beziehen möchte.

Ansonsten stimme ich der Aussage, dass man Nominalform vermeiden sollte, zu.

Comment: "14:30 Uhr Stellschrauben anpassen" wäre aber kürzer.

Answer (score 2):

Die Kritik am Nominalstil richtet sich gegen Allerweltsverben wie *kommen*. Eigentlich sollte es daher *Allerweltsverbenstil* heißen. Nein, dieser Stil war schon immer schlecht und wird es auch immer bleiben.

Viel besser:

> Angesichts der gestiegenen Schichtarbeitsbelastung **hat sich** die Inbetriebnahme der Maschine **verzögert**.

Comment: Dein Beispiel bleibt aber immer noch Nominalstil! Deswegen verstehe ich nicht ganz, wieso es in dem Post gleichzeitig auch "dieser Stil war immer schlecht" heißt ... Ansonsten habe ich meine Frage eher in Bezug auf Nominalstil in seiner Gesamtheit und insbesondere seinen passenden Verwendungsbereich gemeint.

Comment: Deshalb schrieb ich ja, die Kritik richtet sich nicht gegen den Gebrauch von Nomen, sondern gegen Allerweltsverben. Wenn du die *Schichtarbeitsbelastung* zu *Belastung durch Schichtarbeit* aufdröselst, wird der Satz wieder schwieriger verständlich.

Comment: In meiner Erfahrung werden Genitivketten von nominalisierten Verben (statt "normales" Verbgebrauchs) genauso kritisiert, und der Missbrauch von Genitivpräpositionen sowieso. Es geht ja auch um Fälle wie "Entschuldigen Sie das Verzögern der Verbuchung Ihrer Überweisung" vs. "Entschuldigen Sie, dass wir erst jetzt gebucht haben".

Comment: Da geht es nach meinem Sprachempfinden eher um die Verkettung von mehr als zwei Genitiven. Das ist auch ohne *-ung*-Substantive schwer verständlich.

Comment: Ja klar, aber geht es etwa bei dem Nominalstil nicht gerade darum? Sonst wäre es ja nicht mehr so nominal, oder? Übrigens, in meinem Beispiel wurden nur 2 Genitive aneinander geketettet und nicht mehr :) Außerdem kann ich auch noch ein "bei" reinschmeißen, und dann haben wir bloß nur ein Genitiv - wie ich es im verarbeiten OP auch gemacht habe.

Comment: Ist "hat" nicht noch viel mehr ein Allerweltsverb? "... verzögert(e) sich die Inbetriebnahme ...".

Comment: @userunknown: Ich verstehe die Antwort so, dass der Nominalstil nicht bei "Allerweltsverben" eingesetzt werden sollte, nicht, dass diese generell zu vermeiden wären. Eventuell könnte aber von Janka nochmal klargestellt werden, was gemeint ist.

Comment: "hat" ist hier kein Allerweltsverb, sondern ein notweniges Hilfsverb für das Perfekt. Das Vollverb ist "verzögern" und aussagekräftiger als das vorherige "zu Stande kommen". Letzteres ist ziemlich inhaltsleer, den zu Stande kommen kann alles mögliche.

Answer (score 2):

> Was ist sein passender Verwendungsbereich? Briefverkehr, Erläuterungsberichte, Beschwerden, Einsprüche vielleicht?

Lebensläufe würde mir da einfallen.

Ich denke bei Kritik am Nominalstil außer an das, was @miep schreibt, auch an verschachtelte Adjektive und ähnliche Konstrukte, bei denen die Verwendung von Verben optional ist, und die ggf. auch den Sinn entstellen können:

> "Angesichts der gestiegenen Schichtarbeitsbelastung ist eine Verzögerung bei der Inbetriebnahme der Maschine unter Zuhilfenahme der Computermethoden zu Stande gekommen"

vs.

> "Schichtauslastungsbedingte computerunterstützte Maschineninbetriebnahmeverzögerung"

Das klingt wahnsinnig wichtig, technisch und hochgestochen, und hat v.a. im Behörden- und Juristendeutsch seine Stilblüten getrieben. Das sind dann rein fachlich-technische Sprachkonstrukte, die sich mehr an ihrer grammatikalischen Logik messen lassen müssen als an ihrer Verwendbarkeit. Sowas in die Alltagssprache sickern zu lassen, z.B. um Eindruck zu schinden, wäre o.g. schlechter Stil. (Auch das liest man manchmal noch in Lebensläufen.)

Ich würde sogar sagen, dass die Tendenz, überhaupt alle Information in die Substantive zu stecken statt in die Verben, aus diesem Bereich kommt. Das kann ich aber nicht belegen.

Theoretisch gibt es aber auch noch eine sehr moderne Anwendungsmöglichkeit: Auf durchsuchbaren Internetseiten sorgt dieser Stil für eine hohe Anzahl auffindbarer Buzzwords. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Der Nominalstil betont *Zustände*, die er als statische, abstrakte Gegebenheit suggeriert. Der Verbalstil stellt die *Tätigkeit* mit all ihren Aspekten der Zuordnung zum verantwortlichen Subjekt, des zeitlichen Verlaufs sowie kausaler Zusammenhänge in den Vordergrund.

Daher wirkt Verbalstil lebendiger: der Aktor ist im Subjekt klar benannt, das Verb als inhaltliches Hauptwort benennt die Aktivität und der zeitliche Verkauf macht die Aktivität leicht nachvollziehbar.

Beim Nominalstil ist der Leser gezwungen, all diese Informationen aus der Zustandsbeschreibung zu erschließen: wer könnte den Zustand erwirkt haben? In welcher Reihenfolge ist der Zustand zustande gekommen? Was wurde getan, um den Zustand zu erreichen?
Ohne diese Informationen bleibt die Aussage abstrakter und somit schwerer zu verstehen.

Nominalstil ist also nötig, um festzustellende Zustände zu benennen; Verbalstil, um ihre Entstehung plausibel, also nachvollziehbar, zu machen.
Insofern haben beide ihre Daseinsberechtigung; es kommt auf die Mischung an.

**Verbalstil erzielen**

Um Nominalstil zu vermeiden und lebendigere Texte zu erhalten gibt es einige Daumenregeln, die sich auch zur Selbstkontrolle eignen.
Das Ziel ist immer, ein möglichst **einfacher Satzbau mit "SPO"** (Subjekt/Prädikat/Objekt). Die Regeln helfen, diese drei Satzteile mit ausdruckskräftigen Worten zu besetzen.

**Die Suche nach dem Verb**

Die Endung **"-ung"** ist ein substantiviertes Verb und somit ein Kandidat für das eigentliche Verb im Satz.
Etwas subtiler, aber genauso aufzulösen, sind substantivierte Verlaufsformen wie "das Verzögern" statt "die Verzögerung".

Ein solchermassen gefundenes Verb ist im allgemeinen kürzer (ohne das -ung) und hilft, ein abstraktes (Behelfs-)Verb zu ersetzen: "Der Unfall bewirkt eine Verzögerung des Verkehrs" wird zu "Der Unfall verzögert den Verkehr".

**Wer oder was ist das Subjekt?**

Der oft begleitende Passiv im Nominalstil hilft, das Subjekt zu vermeiden oder in Nebenteile des Satzes auszulagern. Jedes **"wird/werden"**, insbesondere zusammen mit **"durch"** hilft auf der Suche nach den Subjekt für den Satz.

Das Subjekt ausdrücklich zu nennen ist einer der Hauptvorteile des Verbalstils.
Der Verbalstil ordnet Verantwortung zu, statt sie vage zu vermeiden.

**Was ist betroffen - das Objekt**

Die verbleibenden Substantive enthalten in der Regel auch das Objekt der Tätigkeit. Da die Tätigkeit ja in einem Hauptwort "versteckt" war, ist das Objekt in einer indirekten Position verbunden. Im obigen Beispiel war es ein Genitiv; in Passiv-Sätzen kann es im Dativ stehen.

**Eigenschaften in Adjektiven und Adverbien ausdrücken**

Schließlich fördert der Verbalstil, das "wie" in Adjektiven zu beschreiben, um die Tätigkeiten noch besser vorstellbar und nachvollziehbarer zu machen.  Die Adjektive und Adverbien helfen auch, den schematischen SPO-Satzbau aufzulockern.

**Anwendungsfälle**

Eigentlich gibt es keinen Grund, Texte weniger verständlich, weniger persönlich und weniger abwechslungsreich zu gestalten. Dies gilt für literarische wie funktionale Texte.

Nominalstil fördert Unpersönlichkeit, reduziert oder verwischt Verantwortung, bietet Raum für vage Aussagen mit Lücken und fordert vom Leser unnötigerweise ein höheres Abstraktionsvermögen. Insofern überhöht er den Autor zu Lasten des Lesers - er bestraft dem Leser geradezu mit dem Text.

Insbesondere Lebensläufe, in denen Tätigkeiten (=Fähigkeiten) und der Aktor (=der Bewerber) im Vordergrund stehen, sollten im Verbalstil gefasst sein.
Aber auch juristische, wissenschaftliche oder journalistische Texte profitieren vom Verbalstil.

Comment: "Da die Schichtarbeitsbelastung gestiegen ist, wurde die Maschine später in Betrieb genommen" - hat nun einen anonymen Passiv (der Aktor geht aus dem Beispiel nicht hervor), aber weniger Nominative.

Answer (score 0):

Der Nominalstil ist äußerst schwierig, da mangelnde Vorsicht schnell in eine Sackgasse führt, bspw. ähnlich dem Problem des Musterentwurfs in der Objekt-Orientierten Programmierung. Der imperative Verbalstil ist nicht weniger schwierig, für einfache Sätze aber einfacher und mithin natürlicher, *ich will, ich kann, du musst, du sollst.*

Auf Stackexchange muss das hoffentlich nicht weiter erklärt werden, wenngleich die Analogie nur bedingt tragfähig ist.